# Manually adding sdk for AWS SDK PHP Module

Tags: 7, drush, theming

The AWS SDK for PHP Module comes with a drush make script:

```
; Drush Make (http://drupal.org/project/drush)
api = 2
core = 7.x

projects[awssdk][type] = library
projects[awssdk][download][type] = git
projects[awssdk][download][url] = https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php.git
projects[awssdk][download][tag] = 1.5.10

projects[libraries] = 2
```

What do I need to do to get this SDK manually? I am running Windows and I ran into some issues trying to add the script using drush. I already tried adding the sdk folder to /sites/all/libraries as "awssdk" but that did not work as I keep getting *"Failed to load the AWSSDK"* in Drupal reporting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have git installed, you should be able to run the following from within your /sites/all/libraries directory:

```
git clone git://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php.git awssdk
```

Alternatively, you could use the Zip button on the [Github project page](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php) or the [link it points to](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php/zipball/master) to download the zip file and put it in a subdirectory of libraries directory called [awssdk](http://drupalcode.org/project/awssdk.git/blob/2212f45b36c8831ac654613fb62e698938004888:/awssdk.module#l54).

Comment: It didn't work at first and I could've sworn I cleared the cache before but after clearing the cache it went away. Thanks!

Comment: Call should be git clone `https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php.git awssdk`